# Error in timer trigger Function execution

Tags: python, triggers, azure-functions

while working with timer trigger functions in local mode it is not running as expected.
suppose if I gave it to fire at 12.00 AM it is executing at 9.15 PM. what might be the reasons for this ?

My Ncorn expression : 0 0 0 * * *

My function.json file:

[image]

output of the Terminal after timer trigger function got fired:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and add the `function.json` code and the *error* in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a **Python Timer Trigger Azure Function** to trigger the function at **12:00 AM midnight** by using CRON expression `0 0 0 * * *`.

```py
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 0 0 * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

- Initially, I was not able to trigger the function at `12:00 AM` with CRON expression `0 0 0 * * *`:

[image]

To run the trigger at `12:00 AM`, I had to **reset and manually set the time** and run the function.

- Able to trigger the function at **12:00 AM**

[image]

Comment: hii Pravallika KV, Thanks for your reply !!. I had a question, can you brief where to reset and manually set the time

Comment: @karnaR Try resetting the time in your system's Time and Date settings and let me know if you still face issue.

Comment: @ pravallika (https://ibb.co/3dkKdnF) This is the image link of my time and date settings. what to change here?

Comment: Go to `Date and Time` and check if you can manually set the time.